# take data difference of .xmf file on Paraview

Tags: python, vtk, difference, paraview

Hello Computer Science community,

I have an .xmf file that I plot on Paraview using Xdmf reader that is available in Paraview. This file is surface topography and has information about X and Y coordinates/ particles inside (it has point arrays I guess). It also covers 65 time steps. In other words, it includes the information of topography for each time step.

As you all know, it is possible to make a movie by just clicking the play button. What I am interested is that, what amount of increase or decrease in surface topog. happens in each time step "relative to the initial time step and/or time step before the current time". By that way, I will be able to see what is actually happening inside the model and how the topography evolves in time. If I can convert my original file to the one I imagine, then I would record the topographic evolution and compare this with other things as well.

I really need a good explanations since I am beginner at this stage, and the python codes I found on the web just did not work at all. All things evolve around vtk files, or sth like that, and they don't work out for me.

Any help/idea/comment is highly appreciated.

Comment: You could display the time derivative of the topography to show the evolution between two time-steps. Are you interested ? It is difficult to compute such quantities with ParaView, because ParaView standard filters work with the data at a given time frame (so you cannot get the data from the following time frame). However a simple workaround is to use the h5py python module to read the data, compute the time-derivative, and write a new file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, time derivative is also a good information to share. I will look for h5py python module.

Comment: To be precise, `h5py` let you read the data fields of the XDMF binary file (.h5) and store it as numpy arrays.

Comment: I found a python code for that in the link below, but my python says, "No module named xdmf".
http://www.xdmf.org/index.php/Read_Xdmf

Comment: I don't know the `Xdmf` module. If you want to work through the python shell of ParaView, the `h5py` module should be available if you work on Linux. On windows you will have to work outside of ParaView. You can install it manually, or install a python distribution such as `python-xy` or `anaconda`.

Comment: I converted the .xmf file to vtm files. I have 65 vtm files, 65 folders and I have 11 .vtu files in each folder. Now, I can select any timestep I want, but still could not subtract one from the other one by using Paraview programmable filter, or calculator.

Comment: Could you share a few files ? I can make a small demonstrator to show you how to time-average the data with h5py.

Comment: would you kindly provide the demonstration by some random files? as my files are complicated and don't know which one to put in. They include several patches for each file as they were computed in HPC.